How to Test if Video is Playing in Hardware or Software Mode in ExoPlayer
I want to implement the option to choose between hardware and software decoding in ExoPlayer based on user selection. I've implemented the following code:
 private fun buildRenderersFactory(useHardwareDecoders: Boolean): RenderersFactory {
    return DefaultRenderersFactory(this).apply {
        if (useHardwareDecoders) {
            setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF)
                .setMediaCodecSelector { mimeType, requiresSecureDecoder, requiresTunnelingDecoder ->
                    var decoderInfos: List<MediaCodecInfo> = MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT.getDecoderInfos(
                        mimeType, requiresSecureDecoder, requiresTunnelingDecoder
                    )
                    if (MimeTypes.VIDEO_H264 == mimeType) {
                        // Copy the list because MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT returns an unmodifiable list
                        decoderInfos = ArrayList(decoderInfos).asReversed()
                    }
                    decoderInfos
                }
        } else {
            setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER)
        }
    }
}

However, I'm not sure if this is working correctly. I want to test whether the video is being played with hardware or software acceleration. I tried the following approach:
private inner class CustomAnalyticsListener : AnalyticsListener {
    override fun onVideoDecoderInitialized(
        eventTime: AnalyticsListener.EventTime,
        decoderName: String,
        initializedTimestampMs: Long,
        initializationDurationMs: Long
    ) {
        Log.d("EXOPLAYER_DECODER", "Video decoder initialized: $decoderName")
    }

    override fun onVideoInputFormatChanged(eventTime: AnalyticsListener.EventTime, format: Format) {
        Log.d("EXOPLAYER_DECODER", "Video input format changed: $format")
    }

    // Override other methods if needed
}

No matter what I select (HW or SW), the decoder name gives me the same result every time: "Video decoder initialized: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec".
How can I accurately test whether my video is being played using hardware or software acceleration in ExoPlayer?

Related: How to know Android decoder MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type) is Hardware or software decoder?

Also found this issue ticket: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4835 via https://medium.com/@juegeorge/exoplayer-enabling-low-end-device-playback-7656aded13fc and looking at the code diff implies Exoplayer has codec priority mechanisms.

@MorrisonChang Thanks for your comment. I noticed that I get OMX.Exynos.avc.dec every time. Does this mean it is only using hardware acceleration?

OMX.Exynos.avc.dec is a hardware codec.
